# Wordpress : Prevent slider to load on mobile device

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the Genesis Framework, static page, with Soliloquy slider on the home page only.  We would like to prevent the slider to load on mobile device to reduce load time.

Any way to do that ? Basically I need to know how to disable some PHP when a mobile device is detected.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) {
    /* Show Slider here */
} ?
```

**Refer HEre [Wp Is mobile](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile)**

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but wp_is_mobile also target tablet & we want the slider to show on tablet, just not on phone.  Any way to target only specific device-width in PHP ?

Comment: i dont think wordpress has any function to detect tablet.

Comment: how ever this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936105/detecting-mobile-or-tablet-device